# What is the symfony way to create an entry in db while migrating?

Tags: symfony, migration

I have a DB created via migrations that is empty while I would like it to be filled.

Let's say I have a table called 'books' with 'title' and 'author'. What I would like to make sure that at least "knitting with dog hair" by "Kendall Crolius" is an entry in the DB.

I know how to do this in SQL and of course, I could simply put a script in my build process, that executes a command to check if such an entry exists and if not create it.

**But what is the Symfony way to create an entry in DB while migrating/setup?**

Comment: Migrations are intended to update production databases.  Say you have deployed your app, used it for awhile and have added a bunch of books.  Now you decide to add another column to books using migrations.  Do you really want to add your dog hair book into your production database?  I'm sort of guessing not but you really need to decide what you want to happen.  Seeding your database is probably best left to a separate fixtures process (as described in several of the answers below) which would be done off-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are **data fixtures**. I think the two most popular options are:

- [doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle)
- [hautelook/alice-bundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle)

With the former you create fixtures in code like this (taken from docs):

```php
class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // create 20 products! Bam!
        for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setName('product '.$i);
            $product->setPrice(mt_rand(10, 100));
            $manager->persist($product);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

You can run them using `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`.

Whereas the latter uses YAML:

```yaml
App\Entity\Dummy:
    dummy_{1..10}:
        name: <name()>
        related_dummy: '@related_dummy*'
```

The command for adding the fixtures is: `bin/console hautelook:fixtures:load`

The AliceBundle has the additional benefit that it comes with integration for [Faker](https://fakerphp.github.io), which lets you generate randomized data as well as static data like you suggested.

edit: The main reason for using fixture files is that you want to be independent from the underlying database. When you use an SQL script you might have to keep multiple versions for each supported DB and sometimes even need to adjust it for different versions (e.g. MySQL 5.7 vs. MySQL 8). An additional benefit is, that changes are usually easier to track in a version history in these files than in SQL, but that is debatable. Since Doctrine Fixtures are written in code you can use inspection tools to check if they are in sync with your entities, making it easier to spot when you need to change them.

That being said, if none of those benefits are an argument and you want to use an SQL script then you should keep schema changes and inserting data separate to prevent any issues. Arguably you should also not use migrations for inserting data. You either run the risk of failing the migration because an ID is already used or not rely on IDs and make it difficult to manage relations between data. You could avoid problems by doing `INSERT IGNORE` but then you will have a hard time identifying if your data is in the state you expect and run the risk of inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks that will do what I want, but so will an SQL script. Why should I prefer fixtures over that?

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549844/what-is-the-symfony-way-to-create-an-entry-in-db-while-migrating/65549937?noredirect=1#comment115891763_65549925). Mixing fixtures & schema change can be risky, because depending on when/where you migrate, your data can have different states. E.g. assuming you want a a new role to have specific id, but that is taken on prod because someone changed existing roles on the live system. You can mess up your data or your migration will becoome unreliable.

Comment: Soo, you did not recommend to use fixtures?

Comment: I do not recommend mixing fixtures with migration. Having just a separate SQL script only for fixtures is ok.The major downside I can think of, is that if you support different databases, say MySQL and Postgres, you will need to maintain multiple scripts. Also managing the SQL script is a bit more difficult. Especially with the Doctrine Fixtures, i.e. fixtures in code, you benefit from static code analysis, that will tell you when the fixtures become out of sync. Updating SQL fixtures when your model changes can be harder to review than in YAML, but that is only a slight drawback.

Comment: Could you add that to your answer? I think others might profit from it too.

Comment: maybe also add how you can execute fixtures from the command  line if you decide to go that road

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend to use fixtures as they are used for test and dev environment, the library should be in the require-dev section in composer.json.
You should create your entities with migration

Comment: I am not sure using migrations for data fixtures is a good idea. This can be problematic, as your fixture data might conflict with "real"/pre-existing data that you have in your database and will make rolling back to an older version problematic, e.g. will you delete data (even if you don't know if it was created by the fixture) or will you just keep it?

Comment: Yes, that was my first intention. But the question is how?

Answer (score 3):

Use a migration with SQL queries (INSERT).
Don't add entities by entity manager, because your entity can be changed (for example: added required field and after that the migration will be executed with an error)

Comment: How would that look like in an application with multiple (e.g. live, dev and local) environments?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for are fixtures : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

You just have to write a file with your fixtures (specifying Kendall Crolius etc.) and run this command at the end of the migration process :

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

Comment: Thanks that will do what I want, but so will an SQL script. Why should I prefer fixtures over that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this is to create a Symfony console command to migrate your data after you have migrated the schema.

I too missed the Laravel seeders when I moved over to Symfony.  I came to realize however that there is nothing that a Laravel seeder can do which cannot be done in a Symfony command.

Migrating the schema and filling the table with data are always two separate operations.  In Laravel the seeders are run separately from the migration.  I've tried migrating data and schema together and it seems that path always led to tears.

Why is that?  I think it is because schema is simple relative to data.   Take your gnarliest production database schema and you can quickly identify the changes you need to accomplish whatever you are trying to accomplish.  But now you've migrated the schema and it is time to migrate 10+ years of production data  into the new order.  Perhaps your data slides right in, but mine seems to always be a rat's nest of horrors that requires a lot of special effort.  My experience is that I might do and undo the schema migration a few times to get it right.  The data migration is something I find that I will do perhaps 10 times because one special case or another has been overlooked.

So it makes sense to build a command specifically to migrate the data for your new schema.  This is quite easy in Symfony.  See https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#creating-a-command to get started.

Briefly the approach is like so.  First create a command template

```
$ symfony console make:command MigrateMyDataCommand
```

Update your template...

```
class MigrateMyDataCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:mydata:migrate';
    protected static $defaultDescription = 'Migrate production data to new schema';
    private EntityManagerInterface $em;
    //...

   // construct to autowire the ORM classes
    private EntityManagerInterface $em;
    private int $maxnew;
    private int $offset;
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    // add arguments to the command
    protected function configure(): void
    {
       $this->addArgument('offset', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'offset to start creating new data');
       $this->addArgument('maxnew', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'maximum new records created.');
   }

   //...

   // execute the command

   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
    $offset = intval($input->getArgument('offset'));
    $maxnew = intval($input->getArgument('maxnew'));
    $io->text('Starting Migrate My Data Command');
    try  {
         $this->em->beginTransaction();
         //...
         $this->em->commit();
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
         $this->em->rollback();
         $io->error('Migration failed');
         return Command::FAILURE;
    }
    $io->success('My data migration successful.');
    return Command::SUCCESS;
}
```

Run your command...

```
$ symfony console app:mydata:migrate 0 1
```

To my mind this is the proper approach.  The data fixtures are perfectly fine for testing where you have a bunch of data you can sling around and not care what happens to it.  Using SQL INSERT is also fine as long as what you are doing is simple.  But if 10,000 users are counting on you to protect their priceless data then I think investing in a specialized command to migrate is the right thing to do.